# Proportional - Monospaced - Uppercase - Lowercase digits

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{EBGaramond-Regular}

\newcommand{\dml}{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Monospaced, Lowercase}}  
\newcommand{\dmu}{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Monospaced, Uppercase}}  
\newcommand{\dpl}{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Proportional, Lowercase}}  
\newcommand{\dpu}{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Proportional, Uppercase}}  

\begin{document}

\dml~ 0123456789
\smallskip
\dmu~ 0123456824789
\smallskip
\dpl~ 012322456789
\smallskip
\dpu~ 012322456789

\end{document}
```

I am trying to figure out a reliable way to switch from numbers in lowercase/uppercase vs. monospace/proportional depending on circumstances.

XeLaTeX throws an error complaining about:

> LaTeX3 Error: The key 'fontspec-opentype/Lowercase' is unknown and is
> being ignored.

I'm looking at the `fontspec` documentation and it states that the features I am using as verified via the `otfinfo` run against the `EBGaramond` font on this Debian stable system are valid.

How can I fix this?

**Update 08/22/20:**

Here's a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{EBGaramond-Regular}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\newcommand{\mon}{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Monospaced}}  
\newcommand{\pro}{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Proportional}}  

\newcommand{\dml}{\addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced, Lowercase}}}  
\newcommand{\dmu}{\addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced, Uppercase}}}  
\newcommand{\dpl}{\addfontfeature{Numbers={Proportional, Lowercase}}}  
\newcommand{\dpu}{\addfontfeature{Numbers={Proportional, Uppercase}}}  

\begin{document}

\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
Monospaced, lowercase   & \dml 0123456780   \\
Proportional, lowercase & \dpl 0123456780   \\
Monospaced, UPPERCASE   & \dmu 0123456780   \\
Proportional, UPPERCASE & \dpu 0123456780   \\
\end{tabular}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. font used needs to support the following features: {lnum, onum, pnum, tnum} — cf. $ otfinfo -f <fontfile_name.otf>
2. looks like if you want to set more than one feature in the same command you must use an extra pair of braces — cf. ... Numbers={Monospaced, Uppercase}

Run the example above e.g. via a "xelatex sample.tex" command to see the result.

Comment: I'm not really up to speed on how OpenType font features are named, but the usual typographic name of what you're referring to as "Lowercase" is "old style".

Comment: Just add some  brackets. E.g., `\newcommand{\dml}{\addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced,Lowercase}}}`

Comment: Scratch that. The brackets remove the error message and produce the desired result in `luatex`, but in `xetex` they only remove the error. On my machine, `luatex` uses Georg Duffner’s EB Garamond, installed in my `~/.fonts`; is `xetex` picking up Octavio Pardo’s version from TeX Live? I wish the two versions had different names…

Comment: @Thérèse good shot. I'd done that in the past with a single feature and I didn't realize I needed the extra braces when changing more than one "feature" via one \newcommand… Also, I'm pretty sure I got EB Garamond from github quite recently… presumably Pardo's version. The Minion Pro font of uncertain origin on my system also has the required features… see my update above.